# how to arrange "prices" in a single responsive column, number of dots depend on the length of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

i have tried this code but this dont give a solution. without using bootstrap table. how could i manage the number of dots for each service. How price comes in a proper column and number of dots can be managed automatically.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead >
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Rates</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td >Federal Incorporation (for profit corporation)......... </td>
     <td class="">$675.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Nonprofit Incorporation</td>
     <td>...........................................</td>
     <td>$975.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Registering Business Name  Master Business License </td>
     <td>$225.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Shareholder’s Agreement</td>
     <td>$1450.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Registering Business Name Master Business License </td>
     <td>$225.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Registering Business Name btaining Master Business License</td>
     <td>$225.00</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image: prices arrange in a straight column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try with a pseudo and a negative margin:

```css
td {
  overflow:hidden;
}
td:first-child:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  margin-right:-100%;
  border-top:dotted;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Rates</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Federal Incorporation (for profit corporation) </td>
      <td>$675.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nonprofit Incorporation</td>
      <td>$975.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Registering Business Name Master Business License </td>
      <td>$225.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shareholder’s Agreement</td>
      <td>$1450.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Registering Business Name Master Business License </td>
      <td>$225.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Registering Business Name btaining Master Business License</td>
      <td>$225.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

codepen to play with : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dvJRgY